# SQL Server bulk insert fails, but file imports easily with import wizard

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, flat-file

I have an R script that combines years of FFIEC Bank Call Report schedules into flat files--one for each schedule--then writes each schedule to a tab-delimited, non-quoted flat file suitable for bulk inserting into SQL Server. Then I run this bulk insert command:

```
bulk insert CI from 'e:\CI.txt' with (firstrow = 2, rowterminator = '0x0a', fieldterminator = '\t')
```

The bulk insert will run for a while then quit, with this error message:

```
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

I've searched here for answers and the most common problem seems to be the rowterminator argument. I know that the files I've created have a line feed without a carriage return, so '0x0a' is the correct argument (but I tried '\n' and it didn't work).

Interestingly, I tried setting the fieldterminator to gibberish just to see what happened and I got the expected error message:

```
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1."
```

So that tells me that SQL Server has access to the file and is indeed starting to insert it.

Also, I did a manual import (right click on database, tasks->Import Data) and SQL Server swallowed up the file without a hitch. That tells the layout of the table is fine, and so is the file?

Is it possible there's something at the end of the file that's confusing the bulk insert? I looked in a hex editor and it ends with data followed by 0A (the hex code for a line feed).

I'm stumped and open to any possibilities!

Comment: I would start troubleshooting this by seeing if there's something "special" about the input file. If you open the file in a hex editor, are the line terminators what you expect? Open in a hex editor and see if there any unicode identifiers at the beginning of the file (2 extra bytes that some processes are smart enough to ignore but others not). If you create a file manually in a text editor, can that file be processed? It would be good to narrow the issue down some.

Comment: You said you're using an unquoted file... is it possible some of your field data contains tab, carriage return or linefeed characters?

Comment: The original files I'm processing are tab-delimited with \r\n line endings. My script reads the text into memory, replaces \r\n with a place holder that shouldn't possibly appear in the data (!!~~!!), replaces all other \r or \n with "", then replaces !!~~!! with \n. That could leave extra \t, but I would then get errors reading the text file into R and I don't.

Comment: Okay, this is truly bizarre. I put the first 1000 rows of the file in a text file and tried bulk inserting them. No problem. So I escalated the number of records (2000, 3000, etc.) until it failed. I ultimately found that the insert failed at line 8,490 in the file. I examined that line and the surrounding lines in a hex editor and there is nothing amiss (no extraneous characters). So I tried inserting a file that was made up the first 8,400 lines copied twice (so 16,800 lines total). And it failed! This makes me think there's some sort of size limit or timeout that's happening.

Comment: Update: We have a second SQL Server instance and it occurred to me today to try the same bulk insert with the exact same layout and exact same tab-delimited file. I did and it worked, no problem. So something is broken in the other SQL Server instance.